# Can not set image url into anchor tag using ng-file-upload in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am using `ngFileUpload` to upload the image from drive and I need to bind that selected image into anchor tag. Here is my code:

```
<div ng-repeat="mul in mulImage">
<input type="file" class="filestyle form-control" data-size="lg" name="upload_{{$index}}" id="bannerimage_{{$index}}"  ng-model="mul.image" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" ngf-select="onFileSelect1($index);">
<a href="mul.image" data-spzoom data-spzoom-width="400" data-spzoom-height="400"><img ngf-thumbnail="mul.image" name="pro" id="imgBig" border="0" style="width:32px; height:32px; border:#808080 1px solid;" ng-if="mul.image !=null"></a>
</div>
```

Here when user is selecting any image from drive it's displaying using `img ngf-thumbnail` but here I need same time that particular image URL should set in `a href=""`. I have done something but it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In html:

```
<div ng-repeat="mul in mulImage">
    <input type="file" ng-model="mul.image" ng-change="getFileUrl(mul)">
    <a href="mulImage[mulImage.indexOf(mul)].imageLink"></a>
</div>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.getFileUrl = function(image) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(image.image);
    reader.onload = function () {
        $scope.mulImage[mulImage.indexOf(image)].imageLink = reader.result;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<a ng-href="mul.image"` instead of `<a href="mul.image"`.

Comment: I did as per you but see what it is generating in output.`<a ng-href="mul.image"  href="mul.image">` again same its not setting any url.

Comment: change to `ng-href="{{mul.image}}"`